# What happen if Authentication mode is not mentioned in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-8

For my new website, I am using a custom `login.aspx` (simply two text boxes username and password with a button). Actually I don't know about authentication modes in ASP.NET. Do I need to specify any mode in my `web.config`?

What are the security issues related to this?

Any links to articles related to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway thanks for your suggestion. I am using 'Scrypt' based hashing. Form authentication seems easy but its difficult for me to manage cookies, user tables etc. I use User table for many other purpose also.
This method gives me a good control over everything even if its difficult to get coded.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ASP.NET Identity. This is the way to handle authentication/authorization in ASP.NET these days.
Start reading the introduction on the asp.net site and a lot of thing will become clear.

Just a login.aspx page will bring you nothing, since there's a lot more involved then just username/password checking. You need to store usernames/passwords, encrypt things, handle cookies (persistent or not), handle autorization, maybe some registration or roles etc etc.

All this things can be done with ASP.NET identity. If it's a new website, in VS2013, Individual User Accounts authentication is on by default when creating a new ASP.NET web project. There's a lot of boilerplate code in the project template to get you up and running...

http://asp.net/identity

Comment: Can i use my own encrypted cookies and authorization logic?
Or i need to follow the ASP classic method?
I am building a content sharing website where user login and shares their website. 
There is only few pages, i am not familiar with forms authentication. Is this a good practice to check custom auth cookies (custom) in every page load?

Comment: @VishalKottarathil You really don't want to re-invent the wheel, and you really want a secure website, so i suggest you follow the ASP.NET guidelines on this. They did all the hard work for you (and they are probably much better in it then we are), so why not use it?

Comment: Currently i am not using SSL, so it will be easy to hack. Can i add  custom login tickets (DB) to validate cookie in the ASP authentication mode?

Comment: @VishalKottarathil SSL has nothing to do with your application level authentication. Sure you can do all things yourself, but do you really want to do all database stuff, business logic, password encryption, cookie creation, authentication checking etc yourself?? Really that cost you lots and lots more time... What's your reason to do it yourself?

Comment: Reason for thinking out of box
* Assume there is 25000 users are live!
* For the classic authentication we dont know the number of database calls and server overhead.
* If i can write a custom one, i can determine the number of database calls and can use some ticket cookies

I hope if some method is clear to me, i can easily learn to realize it. As i am not experienced i dont know what to choose.

Comment: @VishalKottarathil Even with 25000 users, you do know the number of database calls. The storage-part is all native entity framework (code first) out of the box, but you can use any other persistent storage you like. You can always monitor database queries etc. I'm not going to try to convince you any more, but out of curiosity please let us know how you accomplished it if you're ready!

Comment: What i plan is (just plan) simply take username and password from user (encrypt), verify with db and validate login with some encrypted session/cookie. 
Validate this cookie/session in every page. If this validation fails user return to login page. 
DB call for login is made only at the time of Login.
25000 users live means, they will be making great mess. Whenever user scroll to bottom DB call occurs to load data. 
How is my plan?